Max value based on criteria among two joint tables in Access
I have two tables in access with different dates for one and the same order ID. In first one I have only one record per order with date. In the second one I have multiple records per order with different dates - different events. I am trying to find the closest date from table 2 to record in table 1.
For example - Table 1 - one record for order 00001
Order 00001, date 20241024

Table 2 - multiple records for order 00001
Order 00001, date 20241023
Order 00001, date 20241022
Order 00001, date 20241021
Order 00001, date 20241020

Expected result is to get the closest past or equal date from table 2 based on date in table 1.
Table 1
Order: 0001, date: 20241020
Order: 0002, date: 20241021
Table 2
Order: 1; date: 20241022
Order: 1; date: 20241019 (closest past date for order 1, no same date record) Expected result
Order: 1; date: 20241018
Order: 2; date: 20241021 (same date for order 2) Expected result
Order: 2, date: 20241018
Expected output for order 1 is 20241019 and for Order 2 is 20241021 I found DMAX formula but don't know how to use it and not sure if relevant for this.
Thank you!

The following SQL should give you the result you are looking for:
SELECT Table1.fldOrder, 
       (SELECT TOP 1 Table2.fldT2Date 
        FROM Table2 
        WHERE Table2.fldOrder=Table1.fldOrder AND Table2.fldT2Date<=Table1.fldT1Date
        ORDER BY Table2.fldT2Date DESC;) AS fldDate 
FROM Table1;

If you need to retrieve more fields from Table2 then you should save the above SQL as a Query object. You can then use it to join to Table2 and access all fields within the Table2 record. The SQL to do this is:
SELECT qryDates.fldOrder, qryDates.fldDate, Table2.fldT2Date, Table2.fld1, Table2.fld2, Table2.fld3 
FROM qryDates 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON qryDates.fldOrder = Table2.fldOrder
                 AND qryDates.fldDate = Table2.fldT2Date;

Using this method reduces the complexity of a single SQL statement and makes it easier to maintain.
